# Making a text editor in Racket. Creating a Key map

Tags: racket, text-editor

I'm attempting to create a text editor in Racket. I've created an editor-canvas class and I'm trying to override the on-char event

```
(define cnv%
  (class editor-canvas% ; base class
    ; Override on-event
    (define/override (on-char event)
      (display (format "event is: ~a" (send event get-key-code))))
    (super-new)))
```

I figured I could use a combination of (get-control-down) and the key to check for navigation, but instead it just seems to be disabling my ability to type in the canvas. I don't think this is the right way to do it but I'm unsure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Your source code only 5 line? On web have some demo only 300 lines editor written by Racket.

Comment: No It's not. I only posted the relevant section that I'm working on. The rest is just setting up the frame width, label name, and menu bars

Comment: I think a better place to ask these questions is on **racket-users** as that is easily where most experienced racketeers and racket-dev's are found. 

(**racket-users** on google groups  [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/racket-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/racket-users)  you can subscribe to the email list or just use the gg web interface)

Comment: I should add that there are some experienced racket devs on so - just not many